# changing a value of a textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a website that one of his functionalities is to calculate the user GPA. So, I made the user enter the courses dynamically and enter the grade and the credit hour of each course. This is the code:

```js
      var countBox = 1;
      var boxName = 0;

      function addCourse() {
        var box1Name = "Course " + countBox;
        var box2Name = "Grade ";
        var box4Name = "Hours ";
        document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML += <br/>
        <input type="text"  + box1Name + " " + value=" " + box1Name + " " />
        <input type="text" id="box2Name" + box2Name + " " + value= " " + box2Name + " "/>
        <select onchange="ChooseContact(this)" style="margin-right: 0.5em";> 
           <option value="95">A+ </option> 
           <option value="90">A </option> 
           <option value="85">B+ </option>
           <option value="80">B </option>
           <option value="75">C+ </option>
           <option value="70">C </option>
           <option value="65">D+ </option>
           <option value="60">D </option>
           <option value="59">F </option >
         </select ><input type="text"  + box4Name + " " value= " " + box4Name + " "   />  <br/>';
        countBox += 1;
      }

      function ChooseContact(data) {

        document.getElementById("box2Name").value = data.value;

      }
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="addCourse()">Add New Course</button>
<br></br>

<span id="responce"></span>
```

Whenever the user enters a new course, four boxes will appear:
1-course name 
2- Grade (by numbers)
3- drop down list contain the grades (A+, A, B+, B....etc). 
4- credit hours

I want that when the user enters A+ for example, the second box's value changed to 95 and when he enters A, the value changed to 90 and so on. 
It worked for me whenever I enter ONE course only but when the user enter two courses and changes the value of the second course, THE VALUE OF THE FIRST course changed.

Any one has a solution to this problem??

Comment: That code is syntactically invalid. You can’t have a multiline string within `'`…`'`.

Comment: you can't do multiline strings in javascript like that. you have to use a backtick  instead of a single quote for multiline strings.

Comment: You never looked at your console and realized you have syntax errors? Did you do any debugging at all?

Comment: The ids of your elements are not unique as soon as you add more than one course. I think this causes your problem.

Comment: I have changed the syntax. 
The syntax here is not the problem, I can solve it 

But can you see the other problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the backticks arround those multiple lines and you can select the prev element with `previousElementSibling` to change the value, and also to preserve the last element when you insert a new one use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead of `innerHTML`:

```js
var countBox =1;
  var boxName = 0;
  function addCourse()
  {
    var box1Name="Course "+countBox; 
    var box2Name="Grade ";
    var box4Name="Hours ";
    document.getElementById('responce').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<br/>
    <input type="text" id="'+box1Name+'" value="'+box1Name+'" " />
    <input type="text" id="box2Name"'+box2Name+'" value="'+box2Name+'" "/>
    <select onchange="ChooseContact(this)" style="margin-right: 0.5em";> 
       <option value="95">A+ </option> 
       <option value="90">A </option> 
       <option value="85">B+ </option>
       <option value="80">B </option>
       <option value="75">C+ </option>
       <option value="70">C </option>
       <option value="65">D+ </option>
       <option value="60">D </option>
       <option value="59">F </option >
     </select ><input type="text" id="'  + box4Name + '" value="' + box4Name + '"   />  <br/>`);
 countBox += 1;
}

   function ChooseContact(data) {
     data.previousElementSibling.value = data.value;
   }
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="addCourse()">Add New Course</button>
<span id="responce"></span>
```